# FLV Keyframes, any explanation?

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flv

I would like to know please, what's the purpose of keyframes in FLV? what are they good for? and in what situations they are more recommended than other situations?

I know that keyframes are used for tweening values to do animation, but I don't get it when I see people talking about it in FLV files ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In video compression [key frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_frame) (see the Video compression section) is just the frame that stores the full image and next frames are made from key frame by applying changes by encoding algorithm, it's the cornerstone of all video compression algorithms.

Comment: so, the more keyframes the less compression factor?

Comment: so, if I want a high seek resolution, I have to increase keyframes number? (n) keyframes number = (n) possible seek positions?

Comment: AFAIK yes and AFAIK again there isn't way to seek to the given time, only to the nearest keyFrame, the same is written in the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#seek%28%29): _Seeks the keyframe closest to the specified location._